# How do I promote WCF Service to Azure Cloud Service?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf, azure, azure-cloud-services

I have an existing WCF service, and a Cloud Service setup in Azure to host it.  Currently we are logging into the remote desktop, finding E\sitesroot\0 and copy\pasting our built code, and then recycling IIS.

When I publish other WCF services to a cloud service, using Visual Studio I can right click the project and choose "Publish to Microsoft Azure...", but for this project I do not have that option. I *think* this is because those other projects are setup as a Web Role, where my problem project above doesnt seem to have that delegation.

What do I need to do to allow me to publish this thing properly, I have a feeling we're doing it wrong and it may cause me grief some time in the future.

Comment: It is because you have a regular WCF service at it seems and not a web role WCF service? do you wanna host it in web or worker role? why don't ypou create a new web role wcf service and move your service there ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following Microsoft Azure MSDN article seems to address your scenario:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh420322.aspx

In summary, you need to:

- Enable a web application for deployment to Azure by opening the
  shortcut menu for a web project in your solution and choose Add Azure
  Deployment Project
- Publish your web application to Azure by opening    the shortcut menu
  for the web project and choose Publish to Azure

Comment: Just what i needed, never knew of this functionality.  Thanks!!